# Angular Select set Initial value and emit changes to component (currently can only do one or the other)

Tags: angular

I have a select element. I can use attribute binding on the option to set an initial value.

```
[selected]="size.val === 10"
```

But then I want my component to get the data when it's updated, so I added

```
ngModel
(ngModelChange) ="setSelectedSize($event)"
```

...now the UI doesn't display an initial value

How can I have acheive both?

Note: My selectedSize variable is correct when I look in Angular dev tools, it corresponds to

```
this.selectedSize = sizes[n]
```

it's just not affecting the UI until after the first selection.

I've played around with ngOnInit and Input, but I'm not making any progress.

Here's the component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'sync',
    template: `
    <label for="size">Size:</label>
    <select id="size"
    ngModel
    (ngModelChange) = "setSelectedSize($event)"
     >
        <option
        *ngFor="let size of sizes"
        [value]="size.val"
        [selected]="size.val === 20"
        >
      {{ size.name }}
    </option>
  </select> 
    `,
  })


  export class SyncComponent{
    sizes = [
      { val: 20, name: 'Large' },
      { val: 10, name: 'Medium' },
      { val: 0, name: 'Small' },
    ];
  
   selectedSize = this.sizes[0];
    
    setSelectedSize(evNum: any) {
        console.log(evNum)
      for (let size of this.sizes) {
        if (size.val == evNum) {
          this.selectedSize = size;
        }
      }
      console.log(this.selectedSize)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the Angular/framework way to do this, but it was the most straightforward for me...

My next step was to revert back to using [selected] and just (change), then I get an actual event.

So I logged the event to the console and I am able to see that each option node has a "selected" boolean so I am just filtering it down and then getting the value.

This works, but typescript is really starting to bother me... ...this is a NodeList and then the Array.from should make it an array, but I can't get my typing through.

```
setSelectedSize(ev: Event) {
        let tgt = ev.target as HTMLElement
        let selOpt: any = Array.from(tgt.children).filter((i: any) => i.selected === true)[0]
        console.log(selOpt.value)
    }
```